# Flutter Dev Tools greyed out

Tags: flutter, debugging, devtools

I want to use Flutter DevTools. But the DevTools button is grey, not clickable.
[image]
Also, I entered this command:

```
C:\Users\Andras\AndroidStudioProjects\nennos_pizza>flutter pub global run devtools
Serving DevTools at http://127.0.0.1:9100
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: I met the same problem. Have you sorted it out?